# const inline std::map in header causes heap corruption at exit

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, inline, stdmap

I want to have const `std::map` in header as a global constant that will be used in other cpp-s. So I declared it as:

```
// header.h
const inline std::map<int, int> GlobalMap = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
```

However, if I include this header in multiple cpp-s, heap corruption happens at exit time because multiple destructors are run for the same memory address.

I've always assumed that inline const is a silver bullet for global non-literal constants. I've declared global `std::string`-s as `const` inline and it worked just fine.

So my questions are:

1. Why is this intended to happen? Doesn't it make `const` inline very error prone?
2. How do I properly declare global `const std::map` in C++17? And how can I ensure that only one global object would be created?

EDIT:
I can reproduce it on the following project in Visual Studio 2017 (/std:c++17, Debug x86)

file_1.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <map>

const inline std::map<int, double> GlobalMap = {{1, 1.5}, {2, 2.5}, {3, 3.5}};

void f1();
```

file_1.cpp:

```
#include "file_1.h"

void f1()
{
    (void)GlobalMap;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "file_1.h"

int main()
{
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just guessing here, but maybe you forgot to add `#pragma once` at the top?

Comment: @Gal no, there was #pragma once at top

Comment: @Gal why would that make a difference?

Comment: Your solution should be just fine. The problem is somewhere else. Please provide a repro case. E.g. you can actually create multiple files in wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/rIFr1GkkKiJ1Ggzh

Comment: @Mikhail maybe it's MSVC-specific error because I can reproduce it in my Visual Studio, but can't in the website that you linked. Unfortunately I can't attach zip here, so I've provided code in the edit.

Comment: Looks like a Visual C++ bug to me. It works fine in the latest 2019, and VS 2017 probably does have a few glitches in its C++17 support.

Comment: This indeed looks like an MSVC bug. Try inspecting symbols in your object files with `DUMPBIN`. `GlobalMap` should have some "weak" type (this is implementation-specific).

Comment: @molbdnilo are you compiling Debug x86? It doesn't reproduce in Release build in 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a Visual Studio bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/static-inline-variable-gets-destroyed-multiple-tim/297876

At the time of posting, the bug has status "Closed - Lower Priority", i.e. it is not fixed.

From [the comment of the Microsoft representative](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/static-inline-variable-gets-destroyed-multiple-tim/297876#T-N687358):

> If you still face this issue in our latest version, please report it as a new problem.

So I'd suggest filing a new problem with a repro-case.

Comment: Will do.

By the way, contrary to what's written in the report, this bug manifests itself in Release build of our application. I can't create a small repro case for that though.

Comment: The note about Release is quite important, I'm sure it influences the way MS guys prioritize issues.

Comment: Update: my bug report was closed as duplicate, the issue was already reported and has been fixed in VS 2019 16.0. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/inline-static-stdmap-member-throws-exception-in-de/339685

Answer (score 2):

In regard to your second question in C++17 you can apply this fix in order to have only one instance of the map across whole project

```
struct Globals
{
    static inline const std::map<int, int> Map = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
};
```

or you could use `extern`:

1. my_global.h

   ```
   #ifndef my_global_h
   #define my_global_h

   #include <map>

   extern const std::map<int, int> GlobalMap;

   #endif /* my_global_h */
   ```
2. my_global.cpp

   ```
   #include "my_global.h"
   const std::map<int, int> GlobalMap = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
   ```

But in my opinion first solution is much better.

**P.S.** I've put your line of code into a header file and after including that header into more than one *.cpp my program compiled and exits without errors and address of `GlobalMap` is the same in all translation units.
So I agree with @Mikhail that it would be great if you provide us with some repro case.